# Is there any way to add lightning component to a page layout?

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, lightning-aura-components

I need to add lightning component to opportunity page layout. Like mobile cards. Is there any way to add lightning component to the page layout?

Comment: AFAIK feature to add lightening component to page layout was supposed to be released in winter 15. But it's missing there. So answer is - for now, its not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the Spring 15 release while Lightning Components is still in beta, there is no way to surface your lightning component into the standard page layout UI. The only options are:

- Lightning Components Tab
- Lightning App Builder Tab (if on the App Builder pilot)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an Simple way 
[image]
1) click the setup option(right top)
2) go to Edit Option Page
3) Drag and drop the custom or standard component into the layout 
4) Finally save the changes[image]

Comment: This doesn't technically answer the question, but upvoted b/c this is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done via Visualforce using < apex:includeLightning />

[Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

It takes a couple extra steps, but it's not too difficult. I've done it and haven't found too many performance issues.