# Add Lightning Component to VisualForce Page or Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

I'm trying to bring a Lightning component through so that it is visible in a VisualForce Component, but a VF page is ok if this isn't doable.

I've checked a number of resources that say similar things: (All non-linked links are http://)

- [Lightning Components in Visualforce](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-in-visualforce/)
- [winter 16 bug ?- $Lightning is not defined. Please try again](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105954/winter-16-bug-lightning-is-not-defined-please-try-again)
- [Showing a Lightning Component/App inside Visualforce Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91674/showing-a-lightning-component-app-inside-visualforce-page)
- [Use An Inline Visualforce Page With Standard Page Layouts](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/05/08/inline-visualforce-pages-with-standard-page-layouts/)
- [Add Visualforce component to any page layout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16779/add-visualforce-component-to-any-page-layout)
- [Is there any way to add lightning component to a page layout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/is-there-any-way-to-add-lightning-component-to-a-page-layout)
- [Lightning Components
  Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf)

I took my code from the Lightning Components
Developer Guide document above when putting together an example.

Lightning Component: contacts.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="ContactController">
    <aura:dependency resource="spanish:contacts" />
    <!-- Handle component initialization in a client-side controller -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!-- Dynamically load the list of contacts -->
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <!-- Create a drop-down list with two options -->
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selection" change="{!c.select}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Contacts" label="All Contacts"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Primary" label="All Primary"/>
    </ui:inputSelect>
    <!-- Display record create page when button is clicked -->
    <ui:button label="New Contact" press="{!c.createRecord}"/>
    <!-- Iterate over the list of contacts and display them -->
    <aura:iteration var="contact" items="{!v.contacts}">
        <!-- If you’re using a namespace, replace with myNamespace:contactList -->
        <c:contactList contact="{!contact}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Lightning Application: TestLightApp.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="spanish:contacts" />
</aura:application>
```

I tried getting things to come through on a VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:includeLightning />
<!--    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />-->
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("spanish.TestLightApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("spanish:contacts",
                                       {label: ""}, 
                                       "lightning",
                                       function(cmp) {
                                           //  Do some stuff
                                       }
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

And a VF Component:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="testComponent" type="String" description="" />
<!--    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js?v=2" />  -->
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <p>
        Hello, World!
    </p>

    <script>
    /*  $Lightning.use("spanish.contacts", function() {});  */

       $Lightning.use("spanish.TestLightApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("spanish:contacts",
                                       {label: ""}, 
                                       "lightning",
                                       function(cmp) {
                                           //  Do some stuff
                                       }
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

When testing the component I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $Lightning is not defined
```

I've tried importing the lightning.out.js file as well as using .

When testing the page I get the following error message:

```
https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/c.TestLightApp/undefined.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)
```

Is anyone able to help out and show me where I'm tripping up please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set up a domain? Try using this `<apex:includeScript value="{!$Site.BaseUrl}/lightning/lightning.out.js?v=2"/>` instead of ` <apex:includeLightning />`

Comment: Hi @RichardN.  I haven't set up a domain for my Dev Org.  I was just planning on using relative urls for when I apply this code to my work and push it to Prod.  I'll set up a domain name and try it.

Comment: Using {!$Site.BaseUrl} didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get a simple Lightning component working in a VF page using the following link: [Peter Knolle: Lightning Components in VisualForce](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-in-visualforce/)
It was listed in the links that I checked, but I didn't use any of the code, just used as a source to check against what I was doing.

When I did an almost direct copy/paste (a few lines removed because fields didn't exist in my Org) into Salesforce, everything worked as expected and I had a basic Lightning component in a VisualForce page, which I was able to add to my page layout.

Comment: Are you able to show this in VF Component ?